# How can I get the DOM (document) for a URL in Javascript ?

Tags: javascript, dom, phantomjs

I want to do somthing like this:

```
var urls = [url1, url2, url3];
for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var doc = getDocumentFor(urls[i]);
    doc.applyFunctionX();
}
```

Is it possible or should I open a page in a Browser (PhantonJS) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function loadFileToElement(filename, elementId)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try
    {
        xhr.open("GET", filename, false);
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var com = document.getElementById(elementId);
            com.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
    catch (e) {
        window.alert("Unable to load the requested file.");
    }
}
```